# Format and append the text file in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

How can i format the fetched local text file (C++ code in a text format) to be properly formatted in my contenteditable div (like what the pasting event does, which brings me the desired format).

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {

    var f = evt.target.files[0];
      console.log(f);
       if (!f) {
        alert("Failed to load file");
           return;
    } 
      if (f.name.indexOf('.txt') == -1) {
            alert(f.name + " is not a valid text file.");
             return;     
                  }    

      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result.replace("\n","<br/>");
        alert( "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
              + "contents: " + contents
        );
          document.getElementById('board').innerHTML = contents;
      }
      r.readAsText(f);

  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/88vtR/3/ by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2523444/vinod-louis

try this string as the text file to open. It lost some of the string like  (due to not using html entities?)

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){

int grade, passingMark=75;

cout<<"Hi there, please enter your mark: ";
cin>>grade;

if( ((grade >= passingMark)||(grade==35)) && (grade<101)){
cout<<"\nPass!";
}

else if( (grade==74) ){
    cout<<endl<<"Almost!";
}

else if( (grade>0) && (grade<70)){
cout<<endl<<"Super Failed!";
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest something like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/88vtR/4/

Where the file is displayed in a `<PRE>` and the file contents is "html entities compliant"

In other words

```
var contents = e.target.result;//.replace("\r\n","<br/>");
contents = contents.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
```

and

```
<pre id="board" contenteditable = "true">
paste the chosen text file here
</pre>
```

[image: I dont see any difference between the two files]

Comment: did you try the string? it still lost some of the string when opened.

Comment: Sorry but i don't see any difference between the two files : http://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Y7M.png

Comment: yeah, right its on my side ill try to figure it out thanks for the help

Comment: Better choice in your case yep ;)

Comment: can you help me here man http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108695/wrap-the-text-with-div-in-every-row